# Construir una tabla con fechas de inicio y fin de periodo

Tags: mysql

¡Hola!

Tengo una tabla con la siguiente estructura:

```
id | fecha_inicio
---+--------------------
10 | 2016-12-01 10:15:00
10 | 2016-12-03 16:02:00
11 | 2016-12-02 11:23:00
```

Deseo construir una consulta que tenga el inicio y el final del periodo, donde, por ejemplo, la fecha final del primer periodo del id `10` es `2016-12-03 16:02:00`. El resultado que busco es algo como lo siguiente:

```
id | fecha_inicio        | fecha_final
---+---------------------+--------------------
10 | 2016-12-01 10:15:00 | 2016-12-03 16:02:00
10 | 2016-12-03 16:02:00 | NULL
11 | 2016-12-02 11:23:00 | NULL
```

¿Hay forma de construir esta consulta usando únicamente expresiones SQL? Sé que es posible construirla usando otros lenguajes, pero me sería mucho más sencillo hacerlo directamente en la base de datos.

Saludos

Comment: ¿Te refieres a que el `Id = 10` pueda tener diferentes fechas de inicio y fecha final? Es decir, el `Id = 10` se puede repetir varias veces?

Comment: @Flxtr Es correcto. Cada `id` puede tener distintas fechas de inicio; se puede asumir que no habrá interseccion en los periodos (cada nuevo registro define un nuevo periodo)

Comment: Si cada registro define un nuevo periodo, no sería mejor que el `Id` sea único, con esto solo defines tu `PrimaryKey` como un consecutivo y la fecha de inicio y fin son las que varían

Comment: @Flxtr El campo `id` no es `Primary key`. Esta tabla registra los eventos de "activacion" de cada `id`.

Comment: Bien, entonces según entiendo, hay una tabla que llamada (la pongo así a modo de ejemplo) `Tabla1` y otra tabla que se llama `EventosActivacionTabla1` donde se relacionan por la columna `Id`. Si ese fuera el caso, yo crearía una tabla intermedia para realizar las relaciones de uno a muchos para que en la tabla pudieras registrar N eventos registrados a una activación

Comment: ¿Cual es la clave primaria de tu tabla?

Comment: @sstan es un campo autonumérico (es irrelevante, creo)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Le estuve dando algunas vueltas a la idea, y creo que encontré la solución: Usar variables de usuario:

- Lo primero que hice fue ordenar por `id` de forma ascendente, y por `fecha` de forma *descendente*, para poder ir "arrastrando" el valor de `fecha`.
- Después, utilicé un pequeño truco con variables temporales: Dado que cuando se asignan valores a variables de usuario en una consulta estas se actualizan *en cada fila*, entonces es posible hacer referencia a su valor anterior *antes de actualizarlas*:

  - Una expresión `case` verifica si el `id` del registro actual es el mismo que el `id` del registro anterior (que está en la variable `@id_ant`):

    - Si el valor de `id` es igual al valor de `@id_ant`, entonces pon el valor de `@f_ini` (que se actualiza en cada fila con el valor de `fecha`);
    - Si el valor de `id` *no* es igual que el valor de `@id_ant`, entonces pon un `NULL`.
  - Después, actualiza los valores de `@id_ant` y de `@f_ini`, para poderlos usar en la fila siguiente.

El resultado quedó así (usé [SQL Fiddle][http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e4522] para que el problema fuera reproducible; agregué algunos valores más para que el ejemplo fuera más claro):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e4522/1)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
create table prueba (
    id int unsigned not null,
    fecha datetime
);

insert into prueba values 
(10, '2016-12-01 10:15:00'),
(10, '2016-12-03 16:02:00'),
(10, '2016-12-05 19:19:00'),
(11, '2016-12-02 11:23:00'),
(11, '2016-12-04 22:00:00'),
(12, '2016-12-05 02:00:00');
```

**Query 1**:

```
-- Contenido original de la tabla:
select * from prueba;
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e4522/1/0)**:

```
| id |               fecha |
|----|---------------------|
| 10 | 2016-12-01 10:15:00 |
| 10 | 2016-12-03 16:02:00 |
| 10 | 2016-12-05 19:19:00 |
| 11 | 2016-12-02 11:23:00 |
| 11 | 2016-12-04 22:00:00 |
| 12 | 2016-12-05 02:00:00 |
```

**Query 2**:

```
-- Consulta original:
select case when @id_ant = id then @f_ini else null end as f_fin
     -- Actualiza el Id y la fecha de inicio
     , @id_ant := id as id
     , @f_ini := fecha as f_ini
from (select @id_ant := 0, @f_ini := null, @f_fin := null) as init, prueba
order by id asc, fecha desc;
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e4522/1/1)**:

```
|               f_fin | id |               f_ini |
|---------------------|----|---------------------|
|              (null) | 10 | 2016-12-05 19:19:00 |
| 2016-12-05 19:19:00 | 10 | 2016-12-03 16:02:00 |
| 2016-12-03 16:02:00 | 10 | 2016-12-01 10:15:00 |
|              (null) | 11 | 2016-12-04 22:00:00 |
| 2016-12-04 22:00:00 | 11 | 2016-12-02 11:23:00 |
|              (null) | 12 | 2016-12-05 02:00:00 |
```

**Query 3**:

```
-- Consulta con los campos y los valores en el orden correcto:
select id, f_ini, f_fin
from (
        select case when @id_ant = id then @f_ini else null end as f_fin
             -- Actualiza el Id y la fecha de inicio
             , @id_ant := id as id
             , @f_ini := fecha as f_ini
        from (select @id_ant := 0, @f_ini := null, @f_fin := null) as init, prueba
        order by id asc, fecha desc
    ) as a
order by id, f_ini
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e4522/1/2)**:

```
| id |               f_ini |               f_fin |
|----|---------------------|---------------------|
| 10 | 2016-12-01 10:15:00 | 2016-12-03 16:02:00 |
| 10 | 2016-12-03 16:02:00 | 2016-12-05 19:19:00 |
| 10 | 2016-12-05 19:19:00 |              (null) |
| 11 | 2016-12-02 11:23:00 | 2016-12-04 22:00:00 |
| 11 | 2016-12-04 22:00:00 |              (null) |
| 12 | 2016-12-05 02:00:00 |              (null) |
```

Answer (score 2):

Se puede lograr también usando `MIN()` en una sub-consulta:

```
select t.id,
       t.fecha_inicio,
       (select min(t2.fecha_inicio)
          from tbl t2
         where t2.id = t.id
           and t2.fecha_inicio > t.fecha_inicio) as fecha_final
  from tbl t
 order by t.id, t.fecha_inicio;
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://rextester.com/GIWB2116)</kbd>

<kbd>[Demo 2](http://rextester.com/OJPB37031)</kbd>

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Funciona bien con una tabla normal, pero desafortunadamente no funciona con tablas temporales (no se puede hacer referencia a una tabla temporal más de una vez en una consulta). Sé que eso no formaba parte de la pregunta original, pero a la hora de tratar de aplicarlo me topé con esa restricción